# Rename a Layer inside CartoDB

Tags: carto, layers

I would like to simply rename a layer inside CartoDB.
I see buttons for the SQL Query, CSS code, and some HTML... but I don't know where to put my code.
`setLayerName('Test')`

Answer (score 1):

Inside the CartoDB Editor you don't need Javascript code at all.

Double click on top of the current name of the layer and it will automatically convert in a text box that you can edit. Then, press Intro to save the new name.

[image: edit name layer cartodb]